# Custom Post Type title not populating

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

I am attempting to get the title displayed for a function. I am sending myself an email to see if I can get this to work for different titles. Currently the only way I can get it to work is via hard coded number inside the get_the_title. my example below works.

```
$tweetingthing = get_the_title(1067);   

    $to      = 'myemail@email.com';
    $subject = 'Hi!';
    $body    =  'Hi,' . chr(10) . chr(10) . 'Hi title= ' .  $tweetingthing . ' page id is   ' . $this_page_id;


    if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $body ) ) {
        echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
    } else {
        echo('<p>Message delivery failed...</p>');
    }
```

I obviously want more than just that one title, I'd like each title to be sent via email. I have tried this:

```
global $post;
//$thePostID = $post->ID;
$wp_query->post;
$this_page_id = $post->ID;
echo $this_page_id ;
$tweetingthing = get_the_title($this_page_id);

    $to      = 'mh@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Hi!';
    $body    =  'Hi,' . chr(10) . chr(10) . 'Hi title= ' . $tweetingthing . ' Post id is   ' . $this_page_id;


    if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $body ) ) {
        echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
    } else {
        echo('<p>Message delivery failed...</p>');
    }
```

This provides null for $tweetingthing and $this_page_id (I know it's a post id I'm trying to get I simply used the variable giving in the example hope that doesn't confuse anyone).

I also tried

```
$tweetingthing = get_the_title($post_id);
```

also tried
    $tweet_post_id = the_ID();
    $tweetingthing = get_the_title($tweet_post_id);

no luck

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$tweetingthing = get_queried_object_id();
```

results in a post title of 0

Addition info:

I'm using a status transition action to make the function fire. When it goes to publish and matches the custom post type it performs.

I'm using a custom post type

How can I get Custom Post Title?

full source code :

```
function intercept_all_status_changes( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
 if ( $new_status == 'publish' && get_post_type( $post ) == 'tweet' ) {
     // Post status changed
     twitter_run_when_published ();
 }
}  
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'intercept_all_status_changes', 10, 3 );


function twitter_run_when_published () {
//
//email the stuffuff
//

 global $post;
 global $wp_query;
 //$thePostID = $post->ID;
 $wp_query->post;
 $this_page_id = $post->ID;
 echo $this_page_id ;

    $to      = 'meanderingmonarch@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Hi!';
    $body    =  'Hi,' . chr(10) . chr(10) . 'Hi title= ' . $tweetingthing . ' Post id is   ' . $this_page_id;


     if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $body ) ) {
         echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
     } else {
         echo('<p>Message delivery failed...</p>');
     }
}
```

So after @nickyoung mentioned this was weird I thought I'd try a if status changes at all send an email. It sent me 4 messages.

The first: title was not there (post status not there)
The second: title was not their (post status not there)
The third: title WAS there (and post status was draft)
The fourth: no title and post status was not there

edit: just cleaned up some jibberish sentences

edit2: Added full source code to see if anything may help

edit3: Added extra info about post status transitions

Comment: Use  $this_page_id as a paramater.

Comment: @ahmetlutfu you mean in     $tweetingthing = get_the_title($this_page_id);  or is there another one?

Comment: What happens if you try using $post->post_title instead of calling get_the_title() ?

Comment: @NickYoung nothing, the email doesn't show the title at all. I have it setup as follows. global $post; and  $tweetingthing = $post->post_title;

Comment: Hmm that is a really weird issue. What exact action/filter are you using to run this code? Edit: did not see edit, looking now.

Comment: @NickYoung you sparked my curiosity. So I had it email me everytime there was a status change: It sent me 4 messages. 

The first: title was not there (post status not there)
The second: title was not their (post status not there)
The third: title WAS there (and post status was draft)
The fourth: no title and post status was not there

Comment: Interesting. Two things. 1. Can you output the status and the post type within the post status filter you have and see what it says? Maybe there is an issue with the if statement? 2. Is there a different hook that might work better like save_post? Or does it need to be on status change?

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like:

```
$custompost = get_post(get_the_ID());
echo $custompost->post_title;
```

You'll find it works. There's clearly a bug somewhere inside the Wordpress core - this is happening to me too for a custom post type. Not sure what triggers it, but the above is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing this overly complicated. You already have the according `$post`, so just pass its ID to your function.

Try it like so:

```
function intercept_all_status_changes( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if (
        $new_status === 'publish'
        && get_post_type( $post ) === 'tweet'
    ) {
        // Post status changed
        twitter_run_when_published( $post->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'intercept_all_status_changes', 10, 3 );

function twitter_run_when_published( $post_id ) {

    $title = get_the_title( $post_id )

    $to = 'meanderingmonarch@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Hi!';
    $body = 'Title: ' . $title . ', ID: ' . $post_id;

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body ) ) {
        echo '<p>Message successfully sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Message delivery failed...</p>';
    }
}
```